# Is there a way to create an object with foreign key being null at first and then to set it later in spring boot JPA?

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, foreign-keys

I have a one to one relation between two classes. I want to create phase items without having to insert candidate Id with it, because I get candidates afterwards so they basically don't exist.

Right now I'm getting the error:

> could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];

because i'm not sending candidateId with it.

This is the first class :

```
public class PhaseItems {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "phaseI_id")
private long id;

private String PhaseItem;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "items")
@JsonIgnore
private List<PhaseTemplate> template = new ArrayList<>();

 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
 @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id", nullable = true)
 private Candidate candidate;
 
 public PhaseItems() {
    super();
 }  



public PhaseItems(long id, String phaseItem) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    PhaseItem = phaseItem;
}



public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getPhaseItem() {
    return PhaseItem;
}


public void setPhaseItem(String phaseItem) {
    PhaseItem = phaseItem;
}







public List<PhaseTemplate> getTemplate() {
    return template;
}



public void setTemplate(List<PhaseTemplate> template) {
    this.template = template;
}



public Candidate getCandidate() {
    return candidate;
}



public void setCandidate(Candidate candidate) {
    this.candidate = candidate;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PhaseItems [id=" + id + ", PhaseItem=" + PhaseItem + ", template=" + template + "]";
}
```

This is the second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "candidats")
public class Candidate {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "candidate_id")
    private long id;
    
    private String fullname;
    
    private String username;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 45)
    private String email;
    
    private String adress;
    
    private String phoneNumber;
    
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    
    
      @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade =  CascadeType.ALL,
                mappedBy = "candidate")
      private PhaseItems phases;
    
    public Candidate(){
        
    }

    public Candidate(String fullname,String username,String email, String adress, String phoneNumber, String password,
            List<JobApplication> appliedJobs) {
        super();
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.password = password;
        this.appliedJobs = appliedJobs;
    }
    
    
    

    public Candidate(String fullname,String username, String email, String adress, String phoneNumber, String password) {
        super();
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

     

    
    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }

    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<JobApplication> getAppliedJobs() {
        return appliedJobs;
    }

    public void setAppliedJobs(List<JobApplication> appliedJobs) {
        this.appliedJobs = appliedJobs;
    }
    
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
```

Comment: This is about JPA, not Spring Boot.

Comment: This should work - how have you created your tables, and what database is used? Turn on SQL logging and see what is being issued to be sure it is complaining about the SQL and constraint you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set column `candidate_id` as nullable in your database. Java attribute `nullable = true` of `@JoinColumn` annotation is ignored.

Comment: Thanks man , it actually worked with annotation without having to set it in database

Answer (score 0):

Is your column « candidate_id » from table phase_items nullable in your schema ?

Comment: I have set (nullable = true) in  declaration inside phase items's class , so i think it should be nullable no ?